# sort company name in alphabetical order

Tags: python-3.x

i need your help as I'm not able to sort company name in alphabetical order

```py
    import http.client
    import base64
    import ssl
    import sys
    import json
    import getpass
    import requests
    import urllib3
    import operator
    import pprint
    #import simplejson as json
    #import itemgetter, attrgetter, methodcaller
    
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    t = "page="
    url = "https://172.24.11.20:9060/ers/config/guestuser?size=100&sortdsc=name&"
    for i in range(1, 2):
    b = str(i)
    m = url + t + str(b)
    #print(m)
    payload={}
    headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'cache-control': "no-cache",}
    result  = requests.request("GET", m, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False, auth=('ers',        
    '123456*mM')).json()
     total = result['SearchResult']['total']
     for k in range(0, 20):
        z = result ['SearchResult']['resources'][k]['name']
        y = result ['SearchResult']['resources'][k]['id']
        url2 = "https://172.24.11.20:9060/ers/config/guestuser/"
        n1 = url2 + y
        payload={}
        headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'cache-control': "no-cache",}
        r2  = requests.request("GET", n1, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False, auth=('ers',     
       '123456*mM')).json()
            b1 = str(r2["GuestUser"]["guestInfo"]["company"])
        
        e = (b1[0])
        #print(e)
        for c in range (k):
            rr = str()
            if e.startswith("A") or e.startswith("a"):
                rr = b1
                print(rr)
            elif e != rr:
                sorted(rr)
                print(rr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know what the problem is here, I'll assume that you can get all company names, and that `b1` is a company name, and that the program will print out all company names in a unorderd fashion.

From this I'd make a list, in the beginning, called companies with `companies = []` and then add all company names to that list with

```py
companies.append(b1)
```

after the outer `for loop` you'll now have a list of all company names. With that, you can sort them with

```py
companies.sort()
```

which will automatically sort alphabeticaly

Please provoide more detail if not fixed